# Is my SQL statement adding to the start of a database instead of the end?

Tags: java, sql

I am currently trying to insert data into a database, and whenever I try to insert something more than once, I can get an error that it is duplicated.
To quickly summarise what I am trying to do, IDs in my database are stored with "ACCXXXX", with variables `a,b,c,x` being characters from my ID.

```
public String generateCustomerId(){
        String customerId=new String();
        int a,b,c,x;
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT idCustomer FROM customer";
            ResultSet rs=db.read(db.connect().prepareStatement(sql));  
         if(!rs.next()){
               customerId="ACC0000";
           }else {
              rs.beforeFirst();
         } while (rs.next()){
            customerId=rs.getString("idCustomer");
            x = Character.getNumericValue(customerId.charAt(6));
            a = Character.getNumericValue(customerId.charAt(3));
            b= Character.getNumericValue(customerId.charAt(4));
            c = Character.getNumericValue(customerId.charAt(5));
            if (x<9){
            x = x+1;
            customerId = "ACC"+a+b+c+x;
            } else if (c<9) {
               c = c+1;
               customerId = "ACC"+a+b+c+x;
            } else if (b<9){
                b = b+1;
                customerId = "ACC"+a+b+c+x;
            } else {
                a = a+1;
                customerId = "ACC"+a+b+c+x;
            }
         }    
        }   catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {

            db.disconnect();
        }  
        return customerId;
```

}

Above is my method. I use `rs.beforeFirst()` to figure out what the first element in my database is and it's always the values that I have recently inserted. However, if I am using previously made values in my database, it all seems to work fine. I cannot get my head around this issue and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You should think of rows in a table in a database as being in a *random order* so there is no "first" or "last" row.  The idea of position within a table only applies when you have a column whos value you can ORDER BY.  I think you should state your ultimate aim as manually iterating all rows and talking about position is based on a misconception I think.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, I just used it to find out where the inserted value was being stored and saw that it was in the first index. By start I mean that it becomes the first index, rather than the last.

Comment: @Kayaman Since OP called `rs.next()` in the `if` statement, it is no longer before first row, so for the `while (rs.next())` loop to see the first row, `rs.beforeFirst()` is needed. Now, doing that `if(!rs.next())` to peek at the first row is not necessarily the best way to do that, but that's another story.

Comment: @JohnDoe Perhaps your small test saw it inserted first, but there is guarantee that will always be the case. SQL specifically defines that inserted rows can be anywhere, and that `SELECT` statements without `ORDER BY` is allowed to returns the rows in any way the system sees fit to do so. Even repeated runs of the same `SELECT` may return the rows in different order. Without `ORDER BY`, you should expect rows to appear randomly, as AlexK said.

Comment: @AlexK.Thank you very much. I gave your point some thought and decided that in my SELECT statement I would order them in a descending order. It now works as it should. Thank you very much to all of you :)

Comment: @Andreas oh right, the logic is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @Kayaman Yeah, the code is **badly formatted**, so let me do this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/